# Why do I use supervisor managed gunicorn automatically quit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

The gunicorn that I manage with supervisor will automatically exit.This is the Flask project I built with Python3.Hope to get your help.
Start command is ：

```
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/app.conf
```

**log：**

```
[2017-10-24 08:41:15 +0000] [10357] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-10-24 08:41:15 +0000] [10357] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (10357)
[2017-10-24 08:41:15 +0000] [10357] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-10-24 08:41:15 +0000] [10360] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10360
[2017-10-24 08:41:16 +0000] [10362] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10362
[2017-10-24 08:41:16 +0000] [10364] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10364
[2017-10-24 08:41:16 +0000] [10366] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10366
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10357] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10360] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10360)
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10362] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10362)
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10366] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10366)
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10364] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10364)
[2017-10-24 08:41:54 +0000] [10357] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

**supervisor config:**

```
[program:app]
directory = /home/ubuntu/Flask-Blog/   
command = /home/ubuntu/Flask-Blog/venv/bin/gunicorn -w4 -b0.0.0.0:8000 manage:app
autostart = true     
startsecs = 5      
autorestart = true
startretries = 3 
user = ubuntu   
redirect_stderr = true 
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 50MB 
stdout_logfile_backups = 20  

stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/Flask-Blog/log/gunicorn.log
stder_logfile = /home/ubuntu/Flask-Blog/log/gunicorn.err
stopasgroup = false
killasgroup = false

[supervisorctl]
[supervisord]
[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

Comment: Duplicate route endpoints/ Logic error can make this happen. Run your app without gunicorn and confirm app is not producing this error

Comment: I started gunicorn with the same command, but that didn't happen.

Comment: I meant run the flask app without gunicorn. See this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: I run the flask app without gunicorn, and there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall and reconfigure the configuration file. It should be what I made wrong in the configuration process.

Answer (score 0):

sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d use this command and it will automatically exit